# Receive an array in Electron from Python script using ZMQ

Tags: python, electron, zeromq

I am making an app in Electron, and I use a Python Script to make queries (SQL).
I need to send the result of the SQL query to Electron to display this data in a Datatable.
I have read that the best way to communicate is using the ZMQ library. But I don't know if it will be the best option.

I am using the following code, which works if the array (result) is small, but if it has several rows, the array is not sent.

I am using the following code, which works if the array (result) is small, but if it has several rows, the array is not sent.
I appreciate the help.

app.py

```
import zmq
from json import loads, dumps
import signal
from threading import Thread

#.......
def dataSocket():
    global message
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:7778")

    while True:
        message = loads(socket.recv())
        #....
        if message['type']=='command':
            result = querySQL() # result = [['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9','val10'],[...],[...],...,[...]]
            socket.send(dumps(result).encode())
#.......
if __name__ == "__main__":

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    Thread(target = dataSocket).start()
```

render.js

```
const ZMQ = require('zeromq');
const { stringify } = JSON;

const dataSock = new ZMQ.Request;
dataSock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:7778");

$('#sendCommand').on("click", async() => {
    await dataSock.send(stringify({ type: "command", data: "" }));
    [dataResponse] = await dataSock.receive();
    $('#result-data').val(JSON.parse(dataResponse.toString()));
    console.log(JSON.parse(dataResponse.toString()));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dumping the SQL query results as a string into a ZMQ message, and kinda hoping that this is parse-able as JSON at the other end in Electron.

My advice would be to adopt something like Google Protocol Buffers, to serialise the data you want to send from Python and deserialise it again in Electron (JavaScript), and use ZeroMQ to transport the serialised data in between. What this does is remove any ambiguity about how Python and Electron / JavaScript are going to treat / parse data. It also allows you to safely have more complex data structures; for example, if also used to serialise your commands, you'd also be able to pass parameters.

In case you've not used them before, you'd describe in a GPB .proto file the message(s) you'd want to send. If your SQL Query is going to return a two dimensional array, it could look something like:

```
message ResultLine
{
    repeated int Values = 1;
}

message Results
{
    repeated ResultLine Lines = 2;
}
```

You then compile that .proto file using the GPB compiler, which can be told to generate both Python and JavaScript source code. This source code defines classes that look like Results and ResultLine, as well as all the code needed to serialise and deserialise them to the GPB wire format. The Results class is, in effect, a two dimensional array of integers.

So, in your python you'd instantiate a new ResultsLine for each row of data in your SQL return, and fill it with the row's values. You'd then add that ResultsLine to a Results object (that you've previously instantiated). When you've done that for every row, you'd do something like (this is pseudo code, not Python)

```
Result = new Result
foreach row in SQLResponse
    ResultLine = new ResultLine
    foreach val in row
        ResultLine.Values.Add(val)
    Result.Lines.Add(ResultLine)

zmqMsg=new ZMQMsg(Results.SerialiseToString())
socket.send(zmqMsg)
```

There's probably a very pythonic way of doing that iteration, and it's possible the repeated Values field has ways of directly ingesting an array (I'm not very familiar with GPB in Python). And at the other end,

```
zmqMsg = socket.recv()
Results = Results.ParseFromString(zmqMsg.Content)
```

et voila, you now have a Results object containing the data you wanted.

A really nice thing about going to all this bother is that, then, you don't really care what is at the other end of the ZMQ socket. It could equally well be C++, C#, Java, Kotlin, Go; both Google Protocol Buffers and ZMQ are very widely supported. You also have great flexibility; if you want to make the message you're sending, simply update the .proto file and recompile, and pretty much all of the work needed to convey the extra message fields is done; you simply have to populate and consume them.

GPB's wire format is binary, but it also has a dialect of JSON. This too can be useful.